# Regular expression explanation (0+1)*1(0+1)*

Tags: regex

I'm trying to understand the regular expression:

#### (0+1)*1(0+1)*

Could you provide examples that matches this pattern?

0+1 means union.
It sounds like logical OR, isn't it? Should we choose between 0 or 1?

01 means concatenation.
It sounds like logical AND, isn't it? Should we use 01 digits together?

(0+1)* means iteration.
Could we iterate 0 or 1 n times? Does ***000011110000*** match (0+1)* pattern?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean logical expression? At the risk of sounding ignorant, I have never come across a regex flavor in which this makes sense.

Comment: Is this a pattern in some file you're going to match against, or is it a regular expression itself? Characters like +, *, and () have different meaning in REGEX than in math expressions, but it's not clear to me what exactly is your meaning with this question.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about regular expressions? The expression you provided is valid - see [samples](http://regexr.com?32f92) - but the explanations below the expression don't seem to make a lot of sense in the context of regular expressions.

Comment: (0+1)*1(0+1)* is a pattern for matching.

Comment: new user tip: upvote/accept the answer if you find it useful or at least hepful.

Comment: @Asad: It's the academic flavour for [regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_language_theory) :-) Indeed, they use `+` for alternation as we would use `|` in the more common flavours. Everything works as the OP explained :-)

Answer (score 6):

If this is to be interpreted as a regex, it matches expressions that contain

```
zero or more sequences of
    (one or more zeros followed by a single one), 
followed by a single one, 
followed by zero or more sequences of
    (one or more zeros followed by a single one)
```

As a boolean algebra expression, if you remove the star, it evaluates to

```
(false OR true) AND true AND (false OR true)
```

which evaluates to true.

Answer (score 3):

```
(0+1)*1(0+1)*
```

If this is a regular expression, it will match

zero digit once or more in a row, followed by "1" digit once

above combination zero or more times, followed by "1" digit

followed by zero digit once or more followed by 1 digit once

above line zero or more times.

```
+
```

in REGEX means "once or more times" appearance of preceding character

```
*
```

in REGEX means "zero or more times" appearance of preceding character

And common brackets "()" are used for grouping an extension.

"0" and "1" in this case are used literally as characters, not as they're numeric values.

to understand how it works, consider the following regex:

```
(a+b)*c(d+e)*
```

with letters understood literally, not as variables.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the output of `YAPE::Regex::Explain`:

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:(0+1)*1(0+1)*)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    0+                       '0' (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                        '1'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  1                        '1'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2 (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    0+                       '0' (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                        '1'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of \2 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \2)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically `(0+1)*` mathes any sequence of ones and zeroes. So, in your example `(0+1)*1(0+1)*` should match any sequence that has 1. It would not match `000`, but it would match `010`, `1`, `111` etc.
`(0+1)` means 0 OR 1.
`1*` means any number of ones.
`11*` or `1+` means one or more occurences of 1.

Comment: It does not match `111`, at least not entirely.

Comment: It wouldn't match 010 entirely either. The problem is with this bit: `(0+1) means 0 OR 1`. Not in the context of a regular expression.

Comment: I dont think he meant regular expressions, from the context of the question it looks more like a logical expression.

Comment: "(0+1) means 0 OR 1" - that's wrong in regular expressions - and that's what the OP asked for. (0+1) means "at least one 0, followed by exactly one 1".

Comment: In the context of logical expressions there are no "sequences" and the asterisk character means nothing. Both are distinct notations for different purposes, and cannot be mixed arbitrarily.

Comment: OP wrote `0+1 means union`. And union means `either 1 or 0`. To be honest I don't know how this type of expressions is called exactly, but I passed a course about them a while ago :)